# Logistic regression in python - beginner - reshaping dataset

Tags: python, reshape, logistic-regression

Hello: I am trying to test a logistic regression model in python. I have a single feature along with the dependent variable in the dataset. When I run a classifier, I get the following message:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[8. 4. 6. ... 5. 7. 3.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

How can I correct this?

Also - this is an unbalanced dataset. The outcome occurs in only about 1% of the records in the dataset. I welcome any suggestions you may have for addressing this, whether it be oversampling, undersampling, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Well from the intel you provided I'd guess that your input array contains X values at even and Y values at odd indices. If that is the case, you can generate your dataset in proper shape using `data = np.stack([V[::2], V[1::2]])`. If that's not the case, you'll need to share more info with us :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a single X and a single Y value. Since there are usually many X variables to predict one Y variable the logistic regression model expects an input like this:

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

This has nothing to do with over or undersampling, your input data is simply not in the right format.

You can turn a 1d into a 2d list like this:

```
X = [1,2,3,4]
X = [[item] for item in X]
```

Or with numpy arrays:

```
X = X.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: I have finally come back to this analysis and am still having trouble with the reshape code. 

Here is the code I am using to import my data:

    data = pd.read_csv(r'T:\dataset.csv') 
    X = data['LACE_SCORE'] 
    y = data['READMIT'] 
    res = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()

    lr = LogisticRegression().fit(X.values.reshape(-1,1), y)

Then, I am trying to run this code:

    model = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state=0).fit(x,y)

Can you please clarify where in my code I should include the reshape statement? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `X.reshape(-1, 1)` instead of `X`.

Comment: Thanks, all. Appreciate your input. I'll give these a try and follow up if I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other solutions, `numpy` has a function [np.atleast_2d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) for promoting from 1D to 2D:

```py
import numpy as np
X2D = np.atleast_2d(X)
```

You might need to take the transpose (`.T`) afterwards.